# Correct term for Parody/Mock writing

Tags: writing-style

I was at the bookstore and came across a book titled, "You have to Fucking Eat" The book was written in the style of a child's picture book while the content and underlying message is more mature aimed at adults/teens with eating disorders.

My friend and I were discussing this style of writing, knowing that there must be a specific term for such a juxstaposition of content and style/apparent audience. The best we could come up with was "parody." While that label fits, I'm not sure that it is most accurate.

Another example is how sometimes Pixar movies have joke or two thrown in for the parents which would go over the heads of the children.

Is there a better word for that than parody?

Comment: I think "parody" is quite appropriate, this sounds like a parody of children's literature.  I think any other term would be *less* accurate.

Answer (score 1):

If 'parody' is not sufficient, then I suggest

> [pastiche](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pastiche),

an artistic work that imitates another, sometimes intentional sometimes not (the latter is often called 'derivative'). A pastiche is also often a collection of such features in a single work. This works not only for stories or music but any kind of art.

Tom Stopppard's 'Rosenkranz and Guildenstern are Dead' is a classic pastiche of Shakespeares 'Hamlet'.

Comment: As to the Pixar movies that have some jokes for the adults too, that is just multi-layered a different kind of structure.